# android studio not working well not displaying packages

Tags: android-studio

hey guys im not new to java but this android studio thing, im definitely not used to it,
so i just want to know what packages/tools i need to download from the sdk manager to get me started (im  currently dev' apps to be run on api 2.3 gingerbread devices ) 
From the sdk manager this is what i did,
i downloaded and installed all the latest android sdk build tools,sdk platiform for 4.4 and 5.0
then i also downloaded the whole 2.3 api 10 since its what i was developing for....
after that when i start android studio,just right in the work space where you see the 'package' menu 
i get nothing displaying,i mean even all the api i installed i still get nothing.
anybody who been using this tool can gimme help.thx 
kind regards **C.B!**

Comment: im using the latest beta version bytheway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open SDK manager, right click on the .exe and select 
"Run As Administrator".

Don't open it from within android studio, find the exe file on your machine. Worked for me when I ran into that problem.

EDIT: You may need to download the sdk separately form here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i

Click VIEW ALL DOWNLOADS and pick the appropriate 'sdk only' download for your machine.

Comment: i did what you said but,nothings showing up,maybe i have to download all the stuff in the sdk manager?

Comment: Oh yes, after you open it download all the APIs you will need for your project, an emulator if you are not testing on a device, and the libraries your project will use.